# Wordpress: Update Custom Field using API Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, rest, api

I am trying to update a custom field using javascript and the Wordpress REST API.

I can easily create a new post using this and it works perfectly:

```
var post = new wp.api.models.Post( { title: 'This is a test post' } );
post.save();
```

However I need to update a posts custom field. I have tried the following code seen here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218261/wp-api-js-backbone-client-how-to-update-post-meta :

```
var parentId = 91; // the post id
var metaData = new wp.api.collections.PostMeta('', {parent: parentId});
metaData.fetch()
.done(function(data) {
    var someKey = data.findWhere({key: 'someKey'});
    someKey.set('value', 'newValue');
    someKey.save({parent: parentId});
});
```

but I just get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: wp.api.collections.PostMeta is not a constructor
```

Any assistance would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NOT A SOLUTION AN ALTERNATIVE

I gave up on this method and instead went a different route using Ajax as outlined here: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-update-custom-fields-with-ajax-in-wordpress

Basically jQuery:

```
jQuery.ajax({ // In Wordpress use jQuery rather than $ to avoid conflict
            url : 'https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // This address will redirect the query to the functions.php file, where we coded the function that we need.
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                action : 'my_action', 
                postid : postid,
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                   //console.log('Updating Field');
            },
            success : function( response ) {


            },
            complete: function(){

            }
});
```

Functions.php

```
function my_action(){
    $order_id = $_POST['postid'];
     // DO something
    echo $return;

    wp_die($order_id = ''); // this is required to terminate immediately and 
    return a proper response
}
```

I will not mark this as the solution as it isn't but its here to help anyone who comes across it.

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

Suppose you have a custom taxonomy **Vehicles**

#### in your javascript

```
var vehicles = new wp.api.collections.Vehicles();
vehicles.create(
  {
    name: 'Truck',
    description: 'A truck or lorry is a motor vehicle designed to transport cargo'
    meta:{
        '_wiki_link': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truck'
    }
});
```

#### in your php

> see *[wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-terms-controller.php:437](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-terms-controller.php#L437)*

```
add_action( 'rest_insert_vehicles', function( $term, $request, $flag ){
    $term_meta = $request->get_json_params()['meta'] ?? [];
    foreach( $term_meta as $meta_key => $meta_value ){
        update_term_meta( $term->term_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    }
}, 20, 3 );
```

---

Had a similar problem, trying to update the term meta from the javascript rest api...

and it seems as though you CANNOT do it purely with javascript...

reason being is, once the term is inserted via the rest terms controller (snippet below)

> see [wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-terms-controller.php#L428](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-terms-controller.php#L428)

```
$term = wp_insert_term( wp_slash( $prepared_term->name ), $this->taxonomy, wp_slash( (array) $prepared_term ) );
```

... the actual details of the term are **NOT** sent to the update portion of this controller

> see [wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-terms-controller.php#L444](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-terms-controller.php#L444)

```
    if ( ! empty( $schema['properties']['meta'] ) && isset( $request['meta'] ) ) {
        $meta_update = $this->meta->update_value( $request['meta'], (int) $request['id'] );

        if ( is_wp_error( $meta_update ) ) {
            return $meta_update;
        }
    }
```

You'll notice that it sends through the `$request['id']` instead of the `$term['id']`, assuming there's a reason for this (maybe you're performing an update instead of a create)

I may be wrong here... but this is what i've concluded